# infer byte size of JSON file stored in cassandra column for each row

Tags: stored-procedures, cassandra, aggregate-functions, cql, querying

I'm querying a vendor's cassandra database to fetch data from a table. The data returned is a JSON file stored as text. I want to determine the average size of the json file in the cassandra table.
Also other stats like max size and min size for each partition.

Can we achieve the above requirement using SELECT+Aggregate functions queries?

Please suggest to get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

`nodetool tablestats` will tell you the min/max/avg for the partitions in a given table.  `nodetool tablehistograms` will give you even finer grained information.